# Проблема с URL в модуле yii-user

Tags: php, yii

Только начал учить Yii столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я скачал модуль yii-user, все работает отлично, вставил меню, как в примере:

```
array(
    'url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->loginUrl,
    'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Login"),
    'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest
),
array(
    'url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->registrationUrl, 
    'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Register"),
    'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest
),
array(
    'url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->profileUrl,
    'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Profile"),
    'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest
),
array(
    'url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->logoutUrl,
    'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Logout").' ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')',
    'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest
),
```

Но при переходу по меню у меня везде в url прибавлялось `/user`. Например я зашел на страницу авторизации `localhost/yii/index.php?r=user/login`  и потом перешел на другую страницу через меню  то получался вот такой url  `localhost/yii/index.php?r=user/test/index`, в следствии чего появлялась 404 ошибка.

Как избавиться от добавления `/user` при переходе?

Comment: насколько я помню чтобы вызвать роут вне модуля нужно в начале дописать /, т.е. ваш тестовый урл должен выглядеть как-то так array('/test/index'), как он выглядит на самом деле?

Comment: блин большое спасибо, я писал просто test/index', просто '/' не поставил